# How can I use the result of an IO action in an non-IO-function?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, io

This function takes an filepath and returns the content of the file.
this file includes a cuple of lines of the same length.
-- It's used to be an primitive picture.

```
parsePicture :: FilePath -> IO()
parsePicture fileName = do
    content <- lines <$> readFile fileName
    print content
```

Now I've tried to implement a function to flip the "picture" vertically:

```
type Picture = [[Char]]

flipVertical :: IO() -> Picture
flipVertical xs = map reverse xs
```

But I only get the following error code:

```
zuP12.hs:24:31: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[[Char]]’ with actual type ‘IO ()’
    • In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘xs’
      In the expression: map reverse xs
      In an equation for ‘flipVertical’: flipVertical xs = map reverse xs
   |
24 | flipVertical xs = map reverse xs
   |                               ^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

How can I use my function flipVertical on the result of parsePicture?

Comment: first your "read picture" function would have to return the picture instead of printing it

Comment: Note that, arguably, the main design goal of `IO` is to _prevent_ having (meaningful) functions of type like `IO Something -> NonIOType`. By forbidding this, we have that any function that performs IO must have `IO` involved in its type. For example, a non-IO function like `f :: Int -> Int` can never perform any IO; if IO is needed, then the type must be `f :: Int -> IO Int`. This is helpful to clearly mark what does IO and what does not.

Comment: "How do I use the result of an IO action in a non-IO function?" You don't, you use a non-IO function to construct an (even bigger) IO action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This function... returns the content of the file.

No it doesn't. It *prints* the content of the file, to STDOUT. For most purposes you should consider information you put to STDOUT to be *gone* – the information has left your program and is now on the terminal screen, or whereever else the user chooses to put it, but not accessible to the program anymore.

(Strictly speaking, it *is* possible to redirect STDOUT back into your own program, but it's a big hack, don't do this.)

Instead, you should change the function so it actually does return the content:

```
parsePicture :: FilePath -> IO Picture
parsePicture fileName = do
    content <- lines <$> readFile fileName
    return content
```

...or simply

```
parsePicture fileName = lines <$> readFile fileName
```

which behaves exactly the same (by the monad laws).

Also, I would rather call this `loadPicture`: parsing shouldn't involve file reading.

Of course, you can still print the contents later on, with something like

```
main = do
   ...
   fooPicture <- parsePicture "foofilename"
   print fooPicture
   ...
```

As for `flipVertical`, this shouldn't have anything to do with `IO` at all. It's simply a pure function

```
flipVertical :: Picture -> Picture
flipVertical xs = map reverse xs
```

which can be used like, for example

```
main = do
   ...
   fooPicture <- parsePicture "foofilename"
   print $ flipVertical fooPicture
   ...
```

or

```
main = do
   ...
   fooVFPicture <- flipVertical <$> parsePicture "foofilename"
   ...
```

Comment: Nitpick: information you print is still in the program - but only if you keep it in some variable - printing it makes no difference.